# I need some help setting overflow scroll on a container that should fill the entire height of the parent container

Tags: html, tailwind-css, overflow

I am trying to set overflow-scroll on a container that I only want to have a maximum height of 100%. However, when I set a maximum height on the parent container and set overflow-scroll on the child container, the child container continues to grow past the parent container.

Here is a tailwind playground link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/opbmcsxpgV

below is the code from the link:

```
<div class="min-h-screen bg-slate-900">
  <div class="flex max-h-full justify-between p-4 w-full flex-wrap flex-col gap-4 bg-slate-700">
    <div class="flex max-h-full flex-wrap grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-1 gap-4 w-full bg-slate-500">   
        <div class="bg-slate-300 max-h-full">
          <div class="bg-slate-100 max-h-full">
            <div class="max-h-full border-2 border-pink-600 pt-4 overflow-scroll">
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
                </div>

                
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="h-full flex grid grid-rows-3 sm:grid-rows-1 gap-4">
            <!--- More content here that does not matter --->
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish to to set a top level container that is the full height and width of the screen and then have all the child contianers have a max height so they do not grow past the screen hence all the max heights I have scattered around. I think what is happening is that since the top-level container has a minimum height set for the screen, everything will continue to grow if the content goes past the screen no matter if the child containers have a maximum height set to full since the parent can continue to grow. I'm not entirely sure how to fix this though.

I've tried a number of combinations of min / max heights on all of the containers but I just cannot seem to get just the container I need to do the `overflow-scroll`

Edit: putting `max-h-[90vh]` on the div that contains all the hello testing divs gave me the result I was looking for but I am not entirely sure how ideal this solution is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-height: 100%` does nothing with when the parent has resolved height where its calculation depends on its content:

```html
<div class="min-h-screen bg-slate-900">
  <div class="flex max-h-full …">
```

Instead, consider moving the `100vh` height constraint:

```html
<div class="bg-slate-900">
  <div class="flex max-h-screen …">
```

With the various flex/grid layouts, ensure the `min-height: min-content` default is overridden with `min-height: 0` on children, so that the child can shrink where necessary.

Avoid applying `flex` and `grid` classes on the same element – both apply `display` value so one class (`flex`) will always be redundant since it would be overridden by the other.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="bg-slate-900">
  <div class="flex max-h-screen w-full flex-col flex-wrap justify-between gap-4 bg-slate-700 p-4">
    <div class="grid min-h-0 w-full grid-cols-2 gap-4 bg-slate-500 sm:grid-cols-1">
      <div class="max-h-full min-h-0 bg-slate-300">
        <div class="flex max-h-full flex-col bg-slate-100">
          <div class="max-h-full overflow-scroll border-2 border-pink-600 pt-4">
            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>Hello From Testing Land</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid h-full grid-rows-3 gap-4 sm:grid-rows-1">
      <!--- More content here that does not matter --->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```